# I am able to fetch the URL from Rancher Stack using Putty. How do I fetch the same URL from a Rancher Stack using shell commands in Jenkins

Tags: bash, docker, jenkins, rancher

```
setenv RANCHER_SECRET_KEY xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
setenv RANCHER_ACCESS_KEY xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
setenv RANCHER_URL http://xxxxxxxx.xxxxx.com:8080
cd /local/mnt/workspace/username/xxxxxxx/
make cluster-up mak​e idcluster | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f1
```

output: http://10.10.120.90:23884

I need the same URL as output from Pre steps build of Jenkins. I am able to do this manually from Putty.

Comment: `setenv` is not a Bash command.  Are you actually using `csh`/`tcsh`?

Answer (score 0):

[Not able to comment, hence replying, will update once I have more info]

Are the RANCHER_SECRET_KEY, RANCHER_ACCESS_KEY environment variables available inside your script running on Jenkins?